# python running coverage on never ending process

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing, coverage.py

I have a multi processed web server with processes that never end, I would like to check my code coverage on the whole project in a live environment (not only from tests).

The problem is, that since the processes never end, I don't have a good place to set the `cov.start() cov.stop() cov.save()` hooks.

Therefore, I thought about spawning a thread that in an infinite loop will save and combine the coverage data and then sleep some time, however this approach doesn't work, the coverage report seems to be empty, except from the sleep line.

I would be happy to receive any ideas about how to get the coverage of my code,
or any advice about why my idea doesn't work. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import coverage
cov = coverage.Coverage()
import time
import threading
import os

class CoverageThread(threading.Thread):
    _kill_now = False
    _sleep_time = 2

@classmethod
def exit_gracefully(cls):
    cls._kill_now = True

def sleep_some_time(self):
    time.sleep(CoverageThread._sleep_time)

def run(self):
    while True:
        cov.start()
        self.sleep_some_time()
        cov.stop()
        if os.path.exists('.coverage'):
            cov.combine()
        cov.save()
        if self._kill_now:
            break
    cov.stop()
    if os.path.exists('.coverage'):
        cov.combine()
    cov.save()
    cov.html_report(directory="coverage_report_data.html")
    print "End of the program. I was killed gracefully :)"
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure here? "Coverage" specifically refers to tests. Are you trying to see which bits of your code actually get executed?

Comment: Do you want to check if your .py files are still alive?

Comment: yes, the code base is enormous, we want to see what areas of code are never reached, and if these areas exist, remove them, or check why they are unreachable.

Comment: @Rizzit I know the files are alive, but I actually want to know exactly what get executed.

Comment: Coverage uses interpreter hooks to be notified of *every line in your code being executed*. This'll significantly degrade performance, are you willing to pay that price?

Comment: For some time, yes. Once I will have enough data I will disable it.

Comment: @MaximDunavicher Crontabs?

Comment: @Rizzit what do you expect the crontab job will do?

Comment: Just asking if your daemon is done by crontab or if your infinite loop is written by yourself

Comment: its a Twisted reactor

Comment: Any update? Did you try my solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/40537402/140837

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently, it is not possible to control `coverage` very well with multiple `Threads`.
Once different thread are started, stopping the `Coverage` object will stop all coverage and `start` will only restart it in the "starting" Thread.
So your code basically stops the coverage after 2 seconds for all `Thread` other than the `CoverageThread`.

I played a bit with the API and it is possible to access the measurments without stopping the `Coverage` object.
So you could launch a thread that save the coverage data periodically, using the API.
A first implementation would be something like in this

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from coverage import Coverage
from coverage.data import CoverageData, CoverageDataFiles
from coverage.files import abs_file

cov = Coverage(config_file=True)
cov.start()


def get_data_dict(d):
    """Return a dict like d, but with keys modified by `abs_file` and
    remove the copied elements from d.
    """
    res = {}
    keys = list(d.keys())
    for k in keys:
        a = {}
        lines = list(d[k].keys())
        for l in lines:
            v = d[k].pop(l)
            a[l] = v
        res[abs_file(k)] = a
    return res


class CoverageLoggerThread(threading.Thread):
    _kill_now = False
    _delay = 2

    def __init__(self, main=True):
        self.main = main
        self._data = CoverageData()
        self._fname = cov.config.data_file
        self._suffix = None
        self._data_files = CoverageDataFiles(basename=self._fname,
                                             warn=cov._warn)
        self._pid = os.getpid()
        super(CoverageLoggerThread, self).__init__()

    def shutdown(self):
        self._kill_now = True

    def combine(self):
        aliases = None
        if cov.config.paths:
            from coverage.aliases import PathAliases
            aliases = PathAliases()
            for paths in self.config.paths.values():
                result = paths[0]
                for pattern in paths[1:]:
                    aliases.add(pattern, result)

        self._data_files.combine_parallel_data(self._data, aliases=aliases)

    def export(self, new=True):
        cov_report = cov
        if new:
            cov_report = Coverage(config_file=True)
            cov_report.load()
        self.combine()
        self._data_files.write(self._data)
        cov_report.data.update(self._data)
        cov_report.html_report(directory="coverage_report_data.html")
        cov_report.report(show_missing=True)

    def _collect_and_export(self):
        new_data = get_data_dict(cov.collector.data)
        if cov.collector.branch:
            self._data.add_arcs(new_data)
        else:
            self._data.add_lines(new_data)
        self._data.add_file_tracers(get_data_dict(cov.collector.file_tracers))
        self._data_files.write(self._data, self._suffix)

        if self.main:
            self.export()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            sleep(CoverageLoggerThread._delay)
            if self._kill_now:
                break

            self._collect_and_export()

        cov.stop()

        if not self.main:
            self._collect_and_export()
            return

        self.export(new=False)
        print("End of the program. I was killed gracefully :)")
```

A more stable version can be found in this [**GIST**](https://gist.github.com/tomMoral/1e8cb60c1f9e6d06065b11758c2b6b21).
This code basically grab the info collected by the collector without stopping it.
The `get_data_dict` function take the dictionary in the `Coverage.collector` and pop the available data. This should be safe enough so you don't lose any measurement.
The report files get updated every `_delay` seconds.

But if you have multiple process running, you need to add extra efforts to make sure all the process run the `CoverageLoggerThread`. This is the `patch_multiprocessing` function, monkey patched from the `coverage` monkey patch...
The code is in the [**GIST**](https://gist.github.com/tomMoral/1e8cb60c1f9e6d06065b11758c2b6b21). It basically replaces the original Process with a custom process, which start the `CoverageLoggerThread` just before running the `run` method and join the thread at the end of the process.
The script `main.py` permits to launch different tests with threads and processes.

There is 2/3 drawbacks to this code that you need to be carefull of:

- It is a bad idea to use the `combine` function concurrently as it performs comcurrent read/write/delete access to the `.coverage.*` files. This means that the function `export` is not super safe. It should be alright as the data is replicated multiple time but I would do some testing before using it in production.
- Once the data have been exported, it stays in memory. So if the code base is huge, it could eat some ressources. It is possible to dump all the data and reload it but I assumed that if you want to log every 2 seconds, you do not want to reload all the data every time. If you go with a delay in minutes, I would create a new `_data` every time, using `CoverageData.read_file` to reload previous state of the coverage for this process.
- The custom process will wait for `_delay` before finishing as we join the `CoverageThreadLogger` at the end of the process so if you have a lot of quick processes, you want to increase the granularity of the sleep to be able to detect the end of the Process more quickly. It just need a custom sleep loop that break on `_kill_now`.

Let me know if this help you in some way or if it is possible to improve this gist.

---

**EDIT**:
It seems you do not need to monkey patch the multiprocessing module to start automatically a logger. Using the `.pth` in your python install you can use a environment variable to start automatically your logger on new processes:

```
# Content of coverage.pth in your site-package folder
import os
if "COVERAGE_LOGGER_START" in os.environ:
    import atexit
    from coverage_logger import CoverageLoggerThread
    thread_cov = CoverageLoggerThread(main=False)
    thread_cov.start()
    def close_cov()
        thread_cov.shutdown()
        thread_cov.join()
    atexit.register(close_cov)
```

You can then start your coverage logger with `COVERAGE_LOGGER_START=1 python main.y`

Comment: Thanks for coming up with this. It uses a number of non-public interfaces in the coverage.py code base.  What public API could coverage.py provide that would make this more supportable?

Comment: Also, why call combine? Why not write each snapshot to a separate file, and then combine them later?

Comment: Coverage could propose an export function that save the current data in a file and do not stop the `Coverage` object. It is quite straight forward to do it if you take a snapshot of the `collector` data (basically what I implemented here). I call combine in this code because the OP was doing so. It makes it more complicated but keep the file count low if you span multiple processes. Also, the code tends to rewrite over files so using `combine` early avoid loosing info. It depends on the number of processes you span over time and their management.

Comment: It is also worth noting that all the methods in the public API of `Coverage` rely on the `get_data` method which stops the collectors. Thus, you have to use non-public methods to get an export like behavior that does not break the data collection.

Comment: Hi @ThomasMoreau thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will try to implement something similar on our code.

Comment: That is without a dought the best answer I have ever received. Thank you very much for you help!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are willing to run your code differently for the test, why not add a way to end the process for the test?  That seems like it will be simpler than trying to hack coverage.

Comment: Because the data should be collected in a seamless manner to the end user, the idea is to collect data from multiple users around the company and combine their results while allowing them to work in a regular way. Also If I will force the processes to restart or stop, that will affect the behavior which will harm the results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pyrasite](http://pyrasite.com/) directly, with the following two programs.

```
# start.py
import sys
import coverage

sys.cov = cov = coverage.coverage()
cov.start()
```

And this one

```
# stop.py
import sys

sys.cov.stop()
sys.cov.save()
sys.cov.html_report()
```

Another way to go would be to trace the program using [lptrace](https://github.com/khamidou/lptrace/) even if it only prints calls it can be useful.