# How to run coverage.py on a long running process?

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, test-coverage

I have a bunch of processes that run continuously on my server. I can modify the invocation command, but it is difficult to kill the process just to get the coverage report. As I understand it, the .coverage file is generated only after the process starts terminating. Is there any way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Coverage reports are intented for unittests and unittests should terminate. I guess your testing approach (if there is one) might be the root of the problem.

Comment: Not sure I have a way for you to do that. Maybe you could suggest an API you'd like to see...

Comment: BTW: this is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39485731/python-running-coverage-on-never-ending-process, but SO won't let me mark it as such because it also has no answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ned! Would it be possible to add an option where the coverage dumps an intermediate .coverage file every n seconds or n operations/lines?

Comment: Klaus, are you suggesting I shouldn't use coverage reports if I want to figure out which sections of the code are hit more often in a (pseudo-)production environment? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyrasite or [lptrace](https://github.com/khamidou/lptrace/)

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40537402/140837) for details.